# The limit of the Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $E\subset R^n$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and let $(f_k)$ be a sequence of non-negative Lebesgue measurable function on E such that $\lim f_k=f$ a.e.
I want to prove that if $\int_E fd\lambda<\infty$,and$$\lim_k \int_E f_kd\lambda=\int_E fd\lambda,$$then$$\lim_k \int_A f_kd\lambda=\int_A fd\lambda$$
for every Lebesgue measurable set $A\subset E$.

Does it hold if $\displaystyle\int_E fd\lambda=\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counter example in the case when $\int f = \infty$:

Take $E = \mathbb{R}$ and set 
$$f_k = 1_{(-\infty, 0)} + 1_{(k,k+1)} \rightarrow 1_{(-\infty, 0)}$$
And take $A = [0,\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, use Fatou's lemma and the sequence $g_k:=f_k+f-|f-f_k|\geqslant 0$.

For the second part, take $f_n:=\chi_{(n,n+1)}+\chi_{(-1,0)}\frac 1x$ and $f:=\chi_{(-1,0)}\frac 1x$, $A:=[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: I don't understand the counterexample.

Comment: It seems doesn't work. Since f=1 $\lim_k \int_A f_kd\lambda=\int_A fd\lambda=1$

Comment: I've edited, the first attempt didn't worked.